# Adding menu items to Android's Recent Screens menu

Tags: android, recent-screens

I would like to make it easier on Android for user to quit (force stop) an app - without needing to go in Settings>Manage applications ... etc. If there already is an easier way, please share.

If not, is there a way to add menu items to Recent Screens menu? I am working on Honeycomb at this point but am equally interested in answers for ICS as well.

Thanks

Comment: Any reason for the down vote? :-)

Comment: So nice to see that my request was satisfied in Ice Cream Sandwich.

Answer (score 0):

You should give a look at this:

```
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Process.html#killProcess%28int%29

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Process.html#myPid%28%29

Comment: @Thomas thanks. What I am hoping for is something with the user-friendliness of iOS wrt to quitting (as opposed to suspending) an app when the user wishes to do so. It looks like I will need to wait until Google sees the value in this.

Answer (score -1):

> I would like to make it easier on Android for user to quit (force stop) an app

Fortunately, this is not possible, because "force stop" has specific ramifications beyond "quit".

> is there a way to add menu items to Recent Screens menu?

Sorry, no.

Comment: I am having a hard time seeing how making a desired user action difficult is fortunate. I think, in this case, iOS has done a better job of enabling the user to realize their intent: quitting an app instead of merely suspending it. Ultimately, Android allows the user to quit (force stop) - but just makes it incredibly tedious.